# In a kotlin multiplatform mobile gradle build, what is an "ivy" repository? Where does it come from and how can I fix/remove it?

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

When working with a Kotlin multiplatform mobile project, I am getting this error while configuring the project. Especially when building it via the default scripts for iOS inside Xcode.

This is the error

```
> Configure project :HomeShared
Kotlin Multiplatform Projects are an Alpha feature. See: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/evolution/components-stability.html. To hide this message, add 'kotlin.mpp.stability.nowarn=true' to the Gradle properties.
The property 'kotlin.mpp.enableGranularSourceSetsMetadata=true' has no effect in this and future Kotlin versions, as Hierarchical Structures support is now enabled by default. It is safe to remove the property.
The property 'kotlin.native.enableDependencyPropagation=false' has no effect in this and future Kotlin versions, as Kotlin/Native dependency commonization is now enabled by default. It is safe to remove the property.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Build file '/Users/vagrant/git/HomeShared/HomeShared/build.gradle.kts' line: 17
* What went wrong:
Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'ivy' was added by build file '/Users/vagrant/git/HomeShared/HomeShared/build.gradle.kts'
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

And this is the `HomeShared/build.gradle.kts` that is mentioned in the error:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10")
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:1.7.10")
    }
}

plugins {
    id("com.android.application").version("7.3.0").apply(false)
    id("com.android.library").version("7.3.0").apply(false)
    kotlin("android").version("1.7.10").apply(false)
    kotlin("multiplatform").version("1.7.10").apply(false)
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete::class) {
    delete(rootProject.buildDir)
}
```

**My questions now are**:

1. Why does it build on some machines, while it does not build on others?
2. What is an "ivy" repository, and how can I remove it and use maven as specified?
3. Where does that "ivy" reference come from? (I never mention it explicitly in the project)

Comment: The error path says "HomeShared/HomeShared/build.gradle.kts", which looks like the project and module both have the same name. That probably also has a build file specific to KMP. ivy is a type of repository, generally. No idea why you'd get that error.

Answer (score 5):

Within the Kotlin repository, Ivy is in use, as can be seen [in this search](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3AJetBrains%2Fkotlin%20ivy&type=code) of the Kotlin repository. That having been said, this error happens due to declaring repositories in `settings.gradle` or `settings.gradle.kts` with the `FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS` flag, ie:

```kotlin
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
```

You can switch that to either `RepositoriesMode.PREFER_PROJECT` or `RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS` (or removing the line altogether, which is the same as `RepositoriesMode.PREFER_PROJECT`), to work around this. You can see more details in this [Kotlin Slack thread](https://slack-chats.kotlinlang.org/t/8141270/hey-all-so-i-ve-had-this-issue-happen-on-both-a-personal-pro).